# How to get an array like the following from mysql through php?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a table like this-

```
event (id,name,date)
```

I need a result set like this

```
$result = array(
    '1'=>array(
        array('id'=>2,'name'=>'foolball match','date'=>'2011-01-23'),
        array('id'=>5,'name'=>'cricket match','date'=>'2011-01-27')
    ),
    '3'=>array(
        array('id'=>11,'name'=>'100 m run','date'=>'2011-03-12'),
        array('id'=>27,'name'=>'Basket Ball','date'=>'2011-03-20'),
        array('id'=>43,'name'=>'foolball match','date'=>'2011-03-29')
    )
);
```

Here array keys (1,3) represents months (jan,mar). 
Events will be stored under these month number key.
Here 2 is missing because there are no events in februry.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: You can start by trying to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = array();
$year = 2011;
$query = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `date`, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `date`) AS `month` FROM `event` WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`) = "' . $year . '" ORDER BY `date` DESC';
$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $result[$row['month']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: avoid using `mysql_query` and friends, instead use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the data, loop through the result set in PHP, processing the date values.

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming events are in this format
$events = array(
    array('id'=>2,'name'=>'foolball match','date'=>'2011-01-23'),
    array('id'=>5,'name'=>'cricket match','date'=>'2011-01-27'),
    array('id'=>11,'name'=>'100 m run','date'=>'2011-03-12'),
    array('id'=>27,'name'=>'Basket Ball','date'=>'2011-03-20'),
    array('id'=>43,'name'=>'foolball match','date'=>'2011-03-29')
);

$result = array();
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $month = (int)date('m', strtotime($event['date']));
    $result[$month][] = $event;
}
var_dump($result);
```